# Create Group Chat android app using Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, chat, whatsapp

I want to create a group chat android app using parse server. In this User should be able to interact with rest of the members just like Whatsapp.

No limits on the Number of users?Can any one help me with this?

Comment: You can take a look at https://www.firebase.com/

Answer (score 1):

**Parse** is meant to be an app backend (save data), a push notification solution, and an analytics solution. None of these are meant for **real time conversations**.

Check out [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/), which is meant for near-real-time messaging.

You will need to host a server, which you may modify to your needs (implement custom functions, packets actually, to which your app will behave accordingly).

There are a lot of [libraries available](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/), if you develop in android SDK, I recommend the last stable release of the [Smack library](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack)